# What's the difference between Search-as-you-type datatype and Edge NGram Tokenizer?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

Can't understand the difference between setting a Search-as-you-type datatype to a field, setting an Edge NGram Tokenizer in analyzer, and adding an index_prefixes parameter. It seems to me that they do the same job after all.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-as-you-type.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-prefixes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edge_ngram is a tokenizer, which means it kicks in at indexing time to tokenize your input data. There is also a edge_ngram token filter. Both are similar but work at different levels.

search_as_you_type is a field type which contains a few sub-fields, one of which is called _index_prefix and which leverages the edge_ngram tokenizer.

So basically, what you see in the edge_ngram tokenizer documentation has actually been leveraged when they decided to add the new search_as_you_type field type.

Answer (score 0):

Rafiqul is correct that search_as_you_go is built using edge_ngram, but it also incorporates the concept of shingles. Shingles are sets of words, which allows search_as_you_go to better handle multi-word queries.

Note that search_as_you_go requires the words to be in the order entered, which is especially ideal for known entities like movie titles than free form documents.